# How to search MongoDB through the comand line with a wildcard

Tags: mongodb, wildcard

I'm trying to search MongoDB for some info using a wildcard.  I'm trying to find all the "agents" near a given zip code using some type of wildcard.  Here's what I have:

```
db.agents.find({company_address:"49085"},{_id:1,email:1,company_address:1}).pretty()
```

For the zip code, can I use something like: `...find({company_address:"490*"}...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex to find patterns in text/strings.

#### Asumming an address starts with a number:

```
...find({company_address:{ $regex: '^490' }})
```

This admits everything after *490* ...

#### Case you wanted to test a zip code, for example:

For example:

```
...find({company_address:{ $regex: '^490[0-9]+$' }})
```

That finds *strings starting with 490 and continued by one or more digits*.

```
...find({company_address:{ $regex: '^490[0-9]{1,5}$' }})
```

This other is for *strings starting with 490 and continued by between 1 or 5 digits*.

```
...find({company_address:{ $regex: '^490[0-9]{1,}$' }})
```

Goes for *starting with 490 and having at least 1 more digit*.

```
...find({company_address:{ $regex: '^490[0-9]{4}$' }})
```

Goes for *starting with 490 and continued exactly by 4 digits*.

The `^` pattern means start of string, and `$` means end of string, that way it ensures it's always a number.

For more info on regex, look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

And you can test some regex at [regex101](http://regex101.com), see you should pick Java Script on the right as MongoDB works with Java Script

Comment: This is perfect. all the answers are zip codes, so the first one works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this "starts with" regex pattern:

```
db.agents.find(
   {
       company_address: /^490/ 
   }, //SQL equivalent like '490%'
   {_id:1, email: 1, company_address: 1}
)
```

given that the `company_address` has a string value.